# How to make Comparable Class in C++

Tags: c++

I want to make an interface in C++.
How can I get op2.radius value in operator overloading statement?
I'd like that Comparable Class can be used for others such as Rectangle, Line etc.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Comparable {
      public:
             virtual bool operator > (Comparable& op2)=0;
             //virtual bool operator < (Comparable& op2)=0;
             //virtual bool operator == (Comparable& op2)=0;
};

class Circle : public Comparable {
      int radius;
      public:
             Circle(int radius=1) { this->radius = radius; }
             int getRadius() { return radius; }
             bool operator > (Comparable& op2)
             {
                  if (radius > op2.radius) // <-- here!
                  return true;
                  else
                  return false;
             }

};

template <class T>
T bigger(T a, T b){
           if (a > b) return a;
           else
           return b;
}

void main()
{
    Circle waffle(10), pizza(20), y;
    y = bigger(waffle, pizza);
    cout << "the bigger one is " << y.getRadius() << endl;
}
```

Comment: You would need to somehow provide access to the radius attribute in the comparable interface, e.g. `virtual int getRadius() = 0` and then compare it by `this->getRadius() > op2.getRadius()`

Comment: Providing getRadius in Comparable is not a generic solution to his problem. I guess the reason for the Comparable class is to use it across multiple classes.

Comment: Are Rectangle and Line comparable with each other and with Circle? If they are, then you should describe the semantics for such comparison to get advice on implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a downcast, there is no generic way to get the radius. 
 If you are sure the only object passed to it will be of type Circle, then a static cast would suffice. 
 If that is not the case then try to use a dynamic_cast to check if it is a Circle object. If it fails then just return false. 
 Note: dynamic_cast would slow down the performance.

```
bool operator > (Comparable& op2)
{
    Circle* foo = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(&op2);
    if (foo && (radius > foo->getRadius()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not efficient, but yeah it works. On a side note you do need a cast, I was just looking at the Java Comparable interface examples and I see casting almost everywhere. For your reference: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/difference-between-comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html

Answer (score 2):

We don't make classes like `Comparable` in C++. C++ is not Java; it has its own idioms. You don't see anything that resembles `Comparable` in the standard library, which is a strong hint of you trying to move in a wrong direction.

In your particular case, it is unclear what `bigger` should do. Do you want to compare circles and triangles? If not, there is no `Comparable` interface that both circles and triangles belong to. If yes, how? By area? (If so, then you can have a `virtual double area()` and a non-virtual `bool bigger()` that calls it). What about circles and spheres? You can compare two circles, or two spheres, but comparing a circle to a sphere just doesn't make a lot of sense.

There is nothing wrong with having both `Circle::bigger` and `Sphere::bigger`, but they just cannot be both overrides of the same virtual function in some hypothetical common base class or interface, even if you can somehow invent a working signature for that function.

Comment: A comparison would only happen among two objects of the same type, or two objects implementing one well-defined behavior (e.g. `getArea()`). If the two `Comparable`s are not of the same type, then the method should throw an exception.

Comment: @彩音M "A comparison would only happen among two objects of the same type". There are problems with this approach either. For example, you can have a Circle and its derived class ColoredCircle. You want to compare them, because it makes sense, but cannot, because they are not of the same type.

Comment: If `Circle` and `ColoredCircle` are separate types, I think a comparable interface is just the tip of the iceberg of the design problems ;)

Comment: @彩音M If you are saying I cannot freely subclass my classes and mix and match any derived instances with your library, then *your* library has a design problem, not mine. Namely, it violates LSP.

Comment: By design problem, I meant that I just don't see a reason why adding color would necessitate subclassing `Circle`. Color is an attribute, not a specialization. Regardless, the comparator method may be overridden by both `Circle` and `ColoredCircle`. `ColoredCircle` may try comparing colors first, by casting `rhs` to `ColoredCircle` (or even `Colored`). If that cast fails, it will invoke the `Circle` class's comparator to test their areas by casting `rhs` as a `Circle`. And like I said earlier, the `Circle` class will throw an exception if `rhs` is not a `Circle`.

Comment: *ColoredCircle may try comparing colors first, by casting rhs to ColoredCircle (or even Colored)*. Great, so by adding color to circles, I will break geometry software which knows nothing about clolors.

Comment: You missed the rest of my comment. *If that cast fails, it will invoke the Circle class's comparator to test their areas by casting rhs as a Circle.* Nothing's broken yet. But, going back to design problems, one of the reasons I said `ColoredCircle` is silly is because comparing colors sounds absurd. How do you compare colors anyway? Is purple greater than orange?

Comment: No, you missed it. The cast does not fail. Both circles are colored. But circles that were equal are now colored differently and thus unequal, which breaks geometry software.

Comment: In fact your proposal just breaks transifivity of equality. A red unit circle is equal to a colorless unit circle which is equal to a green unit circle, but a red unit circle is not equal to a green unit circle.

Comment: `>` and `==` are different operators. You can define them separately, so one checks only area, and the other checks color and area.

Comment: @彩音M And if I want them to be compatible? And if I want the opposite arrangement? And if I have more than two attributes to compare? This Comparable thing is just bringing more questions than answers to the table. Why not study how this problem is solved in other languages?

Comment: I apologize if I came off as annoying or persistent, but this was a productive exchange. I'm not as proficient in C++ as I am in other languages, so I definitely learned some new things.

Comment: No prob ;) if you don't know it yet, you may want to learn how this problem is approached in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to pass in our derived class into the `Comparable` class. This way, we keep the pure virtual functions, but leave the parameter type open. No casting is needed.

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
class Comparable {
public:
    virtual bool operator< (T const& other) const =0;
    virtual bool operator> (T const& other) const =0;
};

class Circle : public Comparable<Circle> {    //  note Circle itself is passed as a template parameter
public:
    Circle(int radius = 1) : radius(radius) {}

    bool operator< (Circle const& other) const { return this->radius < other.radius; }
    bool operator> (Circle const& other) const { return this->radius > other.radius; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Circle const& c) {
        os << "Circle{.radius=" << c.radius << "}";
        return os;
    }

private:
    int radius;
};


int main()
{
    Circle c1{5};
    Circle c2{7};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << (c1 < c2) << std::endl;            //  true
    std::cout << std::max(c1, c2) << std::endl;     //  Circle{.radius=7} 
}
```

<sup>([**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f36bf4fb290249fe))</sup>

Most importantly, note the specialisation of `operator<` and `operator>` in the `Circle` class:

```
bool operator< (Circle const& other) const { return this->radius < other.radius; }
bool operator> (Circle const& other) const { return this->radius > other.radius; }
```

They directly take in another `Circle` as the parameter.

You can define an `Equatable` abstract class similarly with `operator==`. If your derived classes (e.g. Circle, Number, Date) can be compared both for ordering and for equality, you can use multi-inheritance to inherit both `Comparable` and `Equatable`.

An exercise for the reader: implement (à la interface) all 6 relational operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=`) for `Circle`, comparing its radii. Possible solution is here: [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0325a3a05d9014aa).

Comment: Late answer, but, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  hope it helps.